# how to set text type in sailsjs model attribute because text type is deprecated

Tags: mysql, database, model, sails.js

As mentioned in the title, I want to set a model attribute to text instead of string.

I realized text type is deprecated that I can only use string.

```
abc : {
    type :'string',
    maxLength:2255  // max up to 65535
},
```

I am wondering if setting this is the correct way to do it if I want the field to be larger or if I want it to be the same size as `text` I just set the `maxLength: 65535`

Thanks everyone for any advise / suggestions.

Comment: Are you using sails to generate the schema?

Comment: @Glen I was using npm package named I think...`sails-generate-models` (can't really remember the package name)

Comment: So using your example, in sails v1, it is possible to set a columnType variable. this variable indicates the type of physical-level column data type to use for an attribute when Sails creates the database table. So you could do something like `type :'string', columnType: 'longtext'` more info on that can be found [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?columntype).

Comment: @Glen thx so I believe setting `columnType: text` should be working fine and the max length would be 65535 as deault that I do not need to set it right?

Comment: Precisely my friend, maxLength is used as a validation, it checks the data coming from sails before it gets to the data store.

Comment: @Glen thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Glen you should post that as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sails v1, it is possible to set a columnType variable. this variable indicates the type of the physical-level column data type to use for an attribute when Sails creates the database table.

So you could do something like

```
 type: 'string',
 columnType: 'longtext'
```

more info on that can be found [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?columntype).